# Query slow when using order by in combination with a join

Tags: mysql

Given following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `webs_shoutbox` (
  `shoutID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` int(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `message` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ip` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`shoutID`),
  KEY `shoutID` (`shoutID`),
  KEY `name` (`name`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=62982 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_roman_ci |

CREATE TABLE `webs_user` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `registerdate` int(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastlogin` int(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nickname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   ....,
   ....,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`),
  KEY `nickname` (`nickname`),
  KEY `userID` (`userID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3366 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_roman_ci
```

The `webs_user` table contains about 4k records, the `webs_shoutbox` contains about 100k records.

I want to query the database and get data from the two tables, using a `left join`:

```
select shoutID, date, name, message, webs_user.userID
from webs_shoutbox 
left join webs_user on webs_shoutbox.name = webs_user.username 
limit 10;
```

This behaves as expected, and will return the result very quickly (in the ms range). But for my query I need it to order by either date or the shoutID, in order to get the latest ones. So I added an `order by` statement:

```
select shoutID, date, name, message, webs_user.userID  
from webs_shoutbox 
left join webs_user on webs_shoutbox.name = webs_user.username  
order by shoutID desc 
limit 10;
```

Suddenly this query takes 13-14 seconds!? I'm really baffled by this HUGE performance issue. After lot's of reading and googling I am unable to find why it's doing such a horrible job on sorting on the primary key field. When doing a select on the `webs_shoutbox` table with an order by statement, it works fine. Its only in combination with the `join` that the performance drops.

What could be causing this? Why would it be taking this long to do seemingly quick operation (sorting on an PK/index)?

Comment: When you select just with LIMIT MySQL select first 10 records and stops. ORDER BY statement forces MySQL to process all records (and sort them) so it's expectedly takes more time

Comment: @Stan: Should ordering on the `shoutID`, which is the `primary key` for this table not be blazing fast?

Comment: It should. I could be wrong, but it could be slow when apply to join result. You can try to get 10 ordered records from  webs_shoutbox and join result with webs_user. This should be faster. Additional bonus - you don't need to join too many records

Comment: @Stan: Could you give me some hints or an example on how to achieve this with SQL? I would, naively, hope that mysql would be smart enough to first sort and limit and afterwards do the joining. How can I tell mysql this with SQL?

Comment: Posted example as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
SELECT ws.shoutID, ws.date, ws.name, ws.message, webs_user.userID FROM
    (select shoutID, date, name, message 
    from webs_shoutbox 
    order by shoutID
    limit 10) as ws
left join webs_user on ws.name = webs_user.username  
order by shoutID desc limit 10
```

Comment: Thanks, this query is doing what it should (and in about 5ms)!

I was not aware of using this kind of subquery/syntax. Thanks for showing how to limit the results before performing the join.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, the PK has a hash index for joining and a btree index for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (I hope that works because limits the "order by" to one table):

```
select t1.shoutID, t1.date, t1.name, t1.message, webs_user.userID
    from (
        select * 
        from webs_shoutbox 
        order by order by shoutID desc
        limit 10
        ) as t1 
        left join webs_user on t1.name = webs_user.username 
    order by shoutID desc 
    limit 10;
```

And in general, you'd better not use text/char/varchar fields as means of relationship (i.e., foreign key). Working with integer fields and indexing them is faster.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. After fixing some small syntax errors, this query was still performing very slow (13 seconds). The user Stan posted somewhat the same query, but limiting the result in the subquery, which seemed to be a good fix.

I'm aware that using text/varchar is not a good way for relationships between tables, but I inherited this database and if it performs well enough doing joins on those fields...

Comment: I was using MS SQL Server syntax in the sub-query. Fixed.